# Should you ever have a row inside of a row or this will cause problems?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking at this project that is using bootstrap 3.3.

There is a layout page that has:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12 main">
           @RenderBody()
       </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

So the inner page (which will be rendered at the @RenderBody()) looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-12>
   <div class="row">
        // content goes here
   </div>
</div>
```

Currently the display is messed up on mobile.   This is very wrong correct or it is technically ok to have a container with a row, and then a row inside of the parent row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Bootstrap 3 is absolutely ok to have structure like

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 main">
      <div class="row">
        // content goes here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

First of all, you forgot `"` in your example.

`.container` and `.col` has `padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;`. And `.row` has `margin-left: -15px; margin-right: -15px;`, so you can use `.row` inside both `.container` and `.col`. But after `.row` element there should be any `.col` child element, to
compensate negative margin.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 main">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
        // content goes here
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```